# How to migrate dhcp server superscope?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, migration, dhcp-server, export

I have super-scope dhcp server on Windows Server 2008 and I want migrate it to new Windows Server 2016 with all scopes, leases and reservations. Is there any way to do this?
I know there is netsh dhcp server export command but I have read somewhere that this this only applies to normal scopes.

Answer (score 0):

When we did this, a couple of years ago, we used `netsh` to do the bulk of the work.

Effectively, we ran `netsh dhcp server 127.0.0.1 dump > backupfile.tmp`, which wrote our config into *backupfile.tmp*.  The contents of that file are readable -- essentially a list of subsequent `netsh` commands to configure the server.  We used *Notepad++* to do bit of manual pruning on that file (to match our new design), then loaded it back in using `netsh exec backupfile.tmp`.  For us, it satisfied enough of the migration for the remainder to be trivial.

I can't verify your statement regarding only working on normal scopes but, the 2016 version of the `netsh exec` command *can* assign scopes to superscopes.  If you have trouble, the fixup command is `netsh dhcp server 127.0.0.1 scope 192.168.1.0 set superscope NameOfSuperscope` (where `192.168.1.0` is the base address of your scope).

Fixups in *Notepad++* might have to include:

- Bulk-replacing `127.0.0.1` with `\\127.0.0.1` (or vice-versa)
- Saving the file in UTF8/ANSI encoding (rather than Unicode/UCS2)
- *(there may be others -- feel free to comment, if you know of any)*